# Cycle through regex and replace found instance

Tags: regex, perl

I currently have the following:

```
# Pre-append "$" to variable names.
# ['"](?:[^'"]*?(?:\\")*)*["'] Matches strings within double or single quotes.
# (*SKIP)(*F) Causes the preceding pattern to fail. Tries to match the pattern on the right side of the | operator using the remaining strings.

my $temp = $entire_line;    
while ($temp =~ /['"](?:[^'"]*?(?:\\")*)*["'](*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/g){
    my $variable_name = $1;     
    $entire_line =~ s/$variable_name/\$$variable_name/;     
}
```

Given `$entire_line = ((factor0 + factor1) * factor2) + factor0`

I would like my output to be:

`(($factor0 + $factor1) * $factor2) + $factor0`

However, I'm getting:

`(($$factor0 + $factor1) * $factor2) + factor0`

I know this is happening because it is finding the first instance of`factor0` twice. Is there a good way to prevent this from happening and replace the instance that is being found?

Also do I need to use the `$temp` variable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\w+)
```

Use this.Replace with `$$1`.

See dmeo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/17

Comment: That will only work for the given example. Basically also makes the whole complicated parsing unneccessary. But most likely, the `factorn` was just an example.

Comment: @vks Thanks for this. Turns out I didn't need the overly complicated regex. I had been using it earlier and repeated it.

Comment: @Giri i wondered that too.... dont forget too mark the answer correct if it satisfies your question :)

Comment: I cannot show an example, because I have no idea what the real data the OP has looks like. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The long regex is not finding the first `factor0` twice. It's the simple regex in the substitution that does. In order to get that to work, you need to make sure it doesn't find the ones that start with a `$`.

```
    $entire_line =~ s/([^\$])$variable_name/$1\$$variable_name/;
```

---

You can just use `$entire_line` with that solution and get rid of `$temp`, but it's very confusing in general. If this is production code, I suggest you add comments to the code and also to the regex by using the `/x` flag. [Your future self will thank you later](http://xkcd.com/1421/).

---

Check your regex here: http://regex101.com/r/vX0aJ9/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, really. Check the match information on the right: MATCH 1
1. [2-9] `factor0`
MATCH 2
1. [12-19] `factor1`
MATCH 3
1. [23-30] `factor2`
MATCH 4
1. [34-41] `factor0`

Comment: yep, it matches the 4 factors.